# Как прочить содержимое текстового файла из файлового менеджера?Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, файлы, kotlin, текст

создал приложение где у меня есть кнопка "Записать в файл", которая открывает мне файловый менеджер. При выборе файла(например, фото) показывает сейчас путь самого файла.

Вопрос как реализовать открытие (например, текстового файла),чтобы при открытии файла он мне отображал содержимое файла, а не его путь?

Ниже представление код xml разметки и main.activity

```
 **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_path"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Прочитать"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_filePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="записать в файл"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</RelativeLayout>**




     **package com.example.myapplication;

     import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
              TextView txt_pathShow;
              Button btn_filePicker;
              Intent myFileIntent;**



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_pathShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_path);
        btn_filePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_filePicker);

        btn_filePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                myFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                myFileIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(myFileIntent,10);


            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String path = data.getData().getPath();
                    txt_pathShow.setText(path);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: ну видимо прочитать файл и выводить его содержимое, а не getPath()

Comment: а можете пожалуйста подсказать как это должно выглядеть? Касательно кода

Answer (score 0):

А ничего что вы используйте String для получения изображение ?
если это изоброжение то в месте

```
    String path = data.getData().getPath();
```

использейте это

```
Uri uri = data.getData().getData();

imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: В данный момент мне нужно чтобы можно было прочитать и вывести только текстовые файлы(с изображениями работать не нужно)